# what type of armature i should use in 12v dc magnetic 2 pole motor to get more than 8000Rpm

Tags: dc-motor, electromagnetism

i m trying to wind a motor but i am new at this so can any one can tell me how can i wind an armature to get more than 8000 Rpm in a 2 pole magnetic motor
of 12 volts

Comment: Armature in series with the 2 pole windings.  
Wind to withstand the high physical stress the armature must withstand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to characterise the motor is probably to wind the armature with a given number of turns (say, 50 or 100 turns), and measure the speed. That will give you a motor constant (Kv in RPM/volt) for that winding. Now Kv * number of turns will be a constant, so if you need to increase Kv to meet your speed requirements you can do that by proportionally reducing the number of turns.

For example if you measure 3000rpm at 12V with 100 turns,

Kv = 3000/12 = 250rpm/Volt.
Kv * turns = 25000

To reach 8000rpm at 12V,
Kv = 8000/12 = 667rpm/V
Turns = 25000/Kv = 25000/667 = 37 turns.

As there are fewer turns there will be room to use a thicker wire gauge, which could be important as the motor will draw more current.

Note that a 2-pole DC motor is probably not self-starting.

Comment: I'm curious why you say a 2-pole DC motor is probably not self-starting?  Assuming the windings are connected to the commutator correctly, he should have no problem with the motor starting.

Comment: I'm guessing based on the question, that this is a construction project with 2 field poles (such as permanent magnet) and 2 armature poles. These can get stuck in "top dead centre" with no quadrature component of force. (Which is why commercial PMDC motors all have 3 rotor poles or more). If so, when he winds it and it doesn't start itself, there's no need to panic, just give it a push